Sort Unicode strings by the byte values of characters
I'm using PostgreSQL 16 and the collation for my column is en_US.utf8, as in:
create table t (a varchar(10) collate "en_US.utf8");

insert into t (a) values ('a'), ('b'),('{a'), ('{b'),
  ('{a{a'), ('{a{b'), ('{aa'), ('{ab');

Then, if I sort by the column a:
select * from t order by a;

I get:
{a
a
{a{a
{aa
{a{b
{ab
{b
b

I was expecting 'a' before '{a' since 'a' has the codepoint 97 and '{' has the codepoint 123.
Do I need to use a different collation to get Unicode sorting?
My use case uses longer strings, but I think this simple example illustrates the issue I'm having.

Is necessary to specify the collation?

This must be a relatively recent change.  When I run your exact code on my 9.9.25 Postgres, I get the order you'd expect:  a
{a
{aa
{a{a
{ab
{a{b
b
{b

To sort by byte values of the encoding, use COLLATE "C". For other collations like en_US.utf8, byte values are mostly irrelevant.
The manual:

C (equivalent to POSIX)
The C and POSIX collations are based on “traditional C” behavior. They sort by byte values rather than natural language order,
and only the ASCII letters “A” through “Z” are treated as letters.
The behavior is efficient and stable across all versions for a given
database encoding, but behavior may vary between different database
encodings.

CREATE TABLE t (a text COLLATE "C");

fiddle
